# script has a ssl certificate error

Tags: ssl

I've provided some HTML and js to a client so he can embed some charts on their webpage. However, their site is SSL'd and requires all scripts to be served over HTTPS.

My client is saying that the script we provided (hosted in s3.amazonaws) has an SSL certificate error. The page comes up as "Your connection is not private".

What can I do to fix the certificate on my end so that it will be served over HTTPS on their end?

Thanks,
Laurence

Comment: Have you tried replacing `http://` with `https://`?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

Comment: You need to install an SSL certificate on your server. Call your host provider and they will set it up for like $30 a year or something.

Comment: and if you already have an SSL certificate you can just remove the "https:" or "http:" from the url and it will load on whatever protocol the user is using. called protocol agnostic.